# Incorrect Syntax in Dynamic Sql Query

Tags: sql-server

I am using Following Dynamic SQL Query to create a View,

```
DECLARE @var1 varchar(100) 
DECLARE @var2 varchar(2000) 

SET @var1 = 'hello'

SET @var2 =

'CREATE OR ALTER VIEW teams.test5
AS
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(BULK ''https://' + @var1 + '/junk/files.csv'',
               FORMAT = ''csv'',        
              ) AS [output]'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @var2
```

I am not sure what is the syntax error here, but I am getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test5, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near '?'

Comment: Please only tag a single RDBMS!

Answer (score 0):

there seem to be some hidden characters after your line `FORMAT = ''csv'',`

when executing print @var2 it produces the following result

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW teams.test5
AS
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(BULK 'https://hello/junk/files.csv',
               FORMAT = 'csv',????????
              ) AS [output]
```

Comment: when print @var2  and i could see ??? but i don't know how to fix it. Appreciate if could provide some solution for this issue.